# For a file with hundreds of thousands of blocks of data, how can I scan each block to check it contains X number of rows?

Tags: bash, file, awk

I have a huge file that contains blocks of data.  An example of **one** data block is below.

- At the top of the block, "260" indicates how many rows the block
  **should** have.  The problem is that some blocks don't have 260 rows.  **I want to identify those blocks**.
- The second line is a header that distinguishes a block from all other blocks in the file.  The first/top block in the file has i =    0, time =    00000.000. The second block has i =    1, time =    00000.500, and so on for subsequent blocks. The "E =" does not matter.

**Problem:**
some of the blocks do not have 260 rows. That messes up calculations I want to do with the file.  **How can I write a bash script to tell me where in the file to find those blocks?**  Unfortunately, this is beyond my primitive bash script skills.  I would be very grateful for any guidance.

.

```
     260
 i =    39068, time =    19534.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
 Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
 Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
 Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
 Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
 Mg        -1.3612751052       -7.5574060036        0.1309284910
 Mg       -15.3370827391       -1.1830156923       -6.7188280399
 H       -25.9873248868        7.7856564757      -15.3088471263
 H        -7.7675250833        2.5977735010       28.4575972233
 H        -9.4734812532       -4.2213295429       14.2412611145
 H        -3.6844358917        2.2584052865        0.1049152363
 O       -18.0698975152        2.1776522700      -11.0397875030
 O        -3.9062250799        4.3450953228        6.0283195565
 O        -3.5714461764       12.4282336147      -11.6036514440
... (Should have 260 rows, but some blocks don't. How to identify them in a large file?)
```

---

Example of my problem (below). Here's a file where there are four blocks of data. Each block should contain four rows of data (here indicated by "Mg" at the start of each row." The second block only contains three rows of data, however, so my calculation would fail here.

I need to figure out how to find that second block in the file so that I can fix it or delete it.

```
     4
 i =    0, time =    0.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
 Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
 Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
 Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
 Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
     4
 i =    1, time =    0.500, E =     -4062.1986631584
 Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
 Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
 Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
 ****This block (above) is missing a row; I need to find this block.****
     4
 i =    2, time =    1.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
 Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
 Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
 Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
 Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
     4
 i =    3, time =    1.500, E =     -4062.1986631584
 Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
 Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
 Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
 Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
```

Comment: Create a [mcve] that demonstrates your problem (e.g. use 5 rows instead of 260) and [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output of that so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear. The solution will be an awk script, not a bash script, since bash is a shell which is a tool to manipulate files/processes and sequence the calls to tools, it is not a tool to manipulate text. awk, on the other hand, **is** the mandatory tool present on all Unix boxes for your shell to call to manipulate text.

Comment: How are blocks concatenated? What is between blocks? How to know that block begins or ends? Could you post an example what is after these `(260 rows)`? An empty line? Does each block has a constant number of columns (ie. 4 columns) in these 260 rows?

Comment: @KamilCuk, I have added an example file with data blocks to my question.  Does this provide sufficient information?  Yes, everything about the blocks is identical, except for the number values and header "i = x, time = y."

Comment: When you say `I need to find this block.` - and do what? Add rows? Print the block? Print the line number where the block starts? Also print the file name? Something else? Add the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @EdMorton, as I said, I will deal with the block manually when I find it.  I just need to find all blocks that don't have the right number of rows.

Comment: do all lines start with a space in column #1? are there blank lines between blocks?

Comment: OK, and once the tool has found the block it needs to tell you something about it - what is that "something"? Again, please [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @markp-fuso, thank you for asking that.  Yes, there are always five spaces before the "260" (in my first example of a block) or "4" (in my complete example at the end of my question).  There is no line space in between each block.  I was not aware that would matter, sorry.  I'll edit my example.

Comment: @Ed, as I said, I need to identify the block so I can find it in the file.  I need a line number or time step/time number that tells me where to find the block.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's very clear that you need to identify the block and we could help you write a script to do so in any of several different ways which is why I'm encouraging you to show us in your question what output you would like. I don't see where there's any "time step" or "time number" in your input and a "line number" might be the number of the line where the block starts or the line where it ends or something else. It'd really help us to help you if you could simply [edit] your question to show **the** output you want given that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- all lines of interest start with a space in column #1 (per OP's sample input data)
- there may be blank lines between blocks of rows
- the only lines with a single field are the entries designating the number of lines in a block
- there's a single space between the `i` and `=` (the `'header'` line)
- OP has yet to provide sample output so for now we'll just print the `'header'` lines for the blocks with a rowcount mismatch (along with the actual vs expected counts)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
function check_and_print() {

if ( blockcount != rowcount )                      # if we have a mismatch in counts ...
   print header" [ "rowcount" / "blockcount" ]"    # print the current header and our counts

}

NF==0    { next }                                  # skip blank lines
NF==1    { check_and_print()                       # only 1 field => start of a new block so ...
                                                   # check previous block for count issues and then ...
                                                   # reset some variables
           blockcount=$1                           # expected number of rows in the new block
           rowcount=0                              # current count of rows in the block
           next
         }

/^ i = / { header=$0                               # header record; save for later display purposes
                                                   # (if we find a count mismatch)
           next }
         { rowcount++ }                            # increment our row counter

END      { check_and_print() }                     # check last block for count issues
' block.dat
```

This generates:

```
 i =    1, time =    0.500, E =     -4062.1986631584 [ 3 / 4 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a quick hack you could just try:

```
awk 'NF==1{if( rec != expect ) {printf "mismatch in block %d.  %d lines in block, expected %d\n", block, rec, expect} block += 1; expect = $0; getline; rec = -1} 1 { rec += 1} ' input
```

This uses lines with a single entry as an indicator that you're in a new block.  Discard the header with `getline`, reset some counters and count rows. When you read a single entry row, verify that the expected number of rows macthed the actual number of rows and print a message if they do not match.

Note that this is not at all robust.  One commenter below points out that this fails to check the final block, and that can be remedied with:

```
awk '
        function verify(){
                if( rec != expect )
                        printf "mismatch in block %d.  %d lines in block, expected %d\n", block, rec, expect
        }
        NF==1{
                verify()
                block += 1;
                expect = $0;
                getline;  # Discard header
                rec = -1
        }
        1 {rec += 1}
        END{verify()}
' input
```

This should still not be considered robust.

Comment: This is excellent, William!  Thank you so much--and everyone else who has helped out.  This works very fast on my huge files and the output is concise.  Many thanks.

Comment: It's important to really think about what a given solution does, especially if you don't have a comprehensive test suite to run it on. In this case this solution will fail to identify it if the last block in your input file is the one that is missing lines. See also http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for when/how to call getline safely.

Comment: @EdMorton, thank you for that advice.  I will make sure to check the last block manually.  I have not yet checked your solution and will also test that now.  I see someone down-voted it.  Not me.

Comment: @user3292696 Wouldn't it make more sense to simply use a solution that doesn't have the problem than to have to check the last block manually? yeah, when you post small, simple code that doesn't need any explanation it gets flagged by a tool as possibly low quality and then people with  low rep who don't know the domain see that in the "low quality queue", jump on it and downvote. If I added a paragraph of irrelevant poetry to my answer or if I wrote a big, complicated script without any explanation then it wouldn't happen.  It's a real problem on this forum. Oh well.

Comment: @EdMorton, yes, of course it would be best to have a problem-free solution.  I'll check yours shortly and if I can figure it out and it works as I need it to, I have no problem with changing my acceptance of an answer.  I tried the solution I chose first because there it was easy for an Awk newbie like me to implement.  Also, I appreciate your help, but the person whose answer I chose has aimed at solving my problem.  I don't mean to be critical at all.  I appreciate your help.  But I since we're talking about our issues with the forum, mine is people who treat everyone like a lazy student.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you change your accepted answer, just learn how it works and fix the issues. Do you see any difference between people who treat you like a lazy student vs those trying to help you learn how to ask a good question per the rules of this forum (and in general) and identify a good answer while also trying to help you answer your current question? Is it possible we're not treating you like a lazy student but an uninformed one instead and simply trying to help you learn how to ask good questions so you get good answers?

Comment: You're not willing to provide whatever people need to help as you still haven't provided the expected output in your question. If you had simply done that as I requested in [the first comment under your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65508757/for-a-file-with-hundreds-of-thousands-of-blocks-of-data-how-can-i-scan-each-blo/65508989?noredirect=1#comment115816877_65508757) I wouldn't have had to keep asking for it over and over again in additional comments. I don't see any snarkiness in my comments, they all just ask you to provide missing information, sorry you took it that way.

Comment: @William FYI all awk implementations allow user-defined functions, not just some.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for that!  I just checked that it is indeed in the standard.  I thought that was a gnu thing.

Comment: You're welcome. There is in fact 1 version of awk that doesn't support user-defined functions so that may be what you were thinking of but that is old, broken awk (/usr/bin/awk on Solaris) which doesn't support much and what it does support is broken in various ways and there are other awks on Solaris that aren't so crippled (/usr/xpg[46]/bin/awk being closest to POSIX) and so that old, broken awk should never be used or even considered when writing (or commenting on!) scripts.

Answer (score 0):

If the block size *should* be constant in one file (e.g. all blocks are *specified* with size `260` but the actual size might differ), then you can use GNU grep.

For the test case with block size 4 use [this regex](http://regexr.com/5jdrm)

```
grep -Poz '(?<=^|\n) {5}4(((?! {5}4)[^\n]*\n){1,5}|((?! {5}4)[^\n]*\n){7,})(?= {5}4|$)' yourFile
```

And for the actual file with block size 260 use

```
grep -Poz '(?<=^|\n) {5}260(((?! {5}260)[^\n]*\n){1,261}|((?! {5}260)[^\n]*\n){263,})(?= {5}4|$)' yourFile
```

These commands print the entire blocks whose sizes are wrong. You should be able to find those blocks in your file by searching for their index number `i = ...`.

You can pipe the result through `| grep -Poz 'i = *\d+' | tr \\0 \\n` to print only the `i = ...` part.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NF==1 {
    prt()
    expNumLines = $1
    actNumLines = -2
    begLineNr = NR
}
{ ++actNumLines }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( actNumLines != expNumLines ) {
        printf "%s: Block with %d instead of %d lines from line number %d to %d\n", FILENAME, actNumLines, expNumLines, begLineNr, NR | "cat>&2"
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
file: Block with 3 instead of 4 lines from line number 7 to 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ cat file
     4
i =    0, time =    0.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
    4
i =    1, time =    0.500, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
    4
i =    2, time =    1.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
    4
i =    3, time =    1.500, E =     -4062.1986631586
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
```

You can use Perl with a [whole file regex](https://regex101.com/r/NgcYnu/1/) to either filter for the good blocks or print the bad blocks.

Here is filter for the good blocks:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/(^\h+(\d+)\h*$\R*([\s\S]*?))(?=^\h+\d+\h*$|\R*\z)/gm) {
                    $block=$1;
                    $block_count=$2+1;
                    $content=$3;
                    $content =~ s/\v*\z//;
                    $line_count=$content=~ tr/\n//;
                    say $block if $block_count==$line_count;}' file
```

Prints:

```
     4
i =    0, time =    0.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
    4
i =    2, time =    1.000, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
    4
i =    3, time =    1.500, E =     -4062.1986631586
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
Mg        -1.5795350637        4.3136091666       -6.2931048061
```

Here is print the bad blocks:

```
$ perl -0777 -lnE 'while (/(^\h+(\d+)\h*$\R*([\s\S]*?))(?=^\h+\d+\h*$|\R*\z)/gm) {
                    $block=$1;
                    $block_count=$2+1;
                    $content=$3;
                    $content =~ s/\v*\z//;
                    $line_count=$content=~ tr/\n//;
                    say "===\nbad block: line count: $line_count, expected: $block_count\n$block===" 
                                if $line_count!=$block_count }' file
```

Prints:

```
===
bad block: line count: 4, expected: 5
    4
i =    1, time =    0.500, E =     -4062.1986631584
Mg       -13.3685893531       -3.8172224945       -6.5454328304
Mg        -8.0288171797       -9.8589528145       -4.2951766641
Mg       -13.5647837790        3.7714741638       11.0518209867
===
```